# how to golang check a variable is nil

Tags: go

my code is like this, when I use `req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://www.github.com", content)`, it will emit exception:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xb code=0xffffffff addr=0x0 pc=0xaab78]

goroutine 1 [running]:
net/http.NewRequest(0x34f3b8, 0x3, 0x378020, 0x15, 0xfeec4350, 0x0, 0x10738801, 0x0, 0x0, 0x107000e0)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/request.go:570 +0x498
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox056954284/main.go:17 +0xe0
```

but when I use `req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://www.github.com", nil)`, it works, why? how I set the third argument value

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "net/http"
)


func main() {
    client := &http.Client{}
    var content *bytes.Reader
    content = nil
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://www.github.com", content)
    resp, _ := client.Do(req)
    defer resp.Body.Close()
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A go interface consists of a type and a value. An interface is only nil if both the type and the value are nil. You provided a type but no value: Therefore `NewRequest` tried to call Read on a nil struct (the value of the interface).

Comment: But why `content == nil` return `true`

Comment: Because bytes.Reader is a struct, not an Interface. But http.NewRequest takes an io.Reader, which is an interface. You hand it over a type, but with no value -> the interface is not nil.

Answer (score 3):

content is nil by default, don't need to assign it

also, you are ignoring the error returned from NewRequest, don't do that.  It is telling you why it can't generate a request.

Normal error handling would be something like:

```
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://www.github.com", content)
if err != nil {
  // log or complain... req is nil here
} else {
  // do something with req
}
```

all that said if you really just want to know if req is nil, do:

```
if req == nil { 
 // handle nil req
} else {
 // use req
}
```

but as mentioned before, it's much better to handle the error.  if err not nil, then you basically can't trust req to be anything valid.

Answer (score 3):

It is a classic trap of the golang language.

To check if it is a real Nil:

```
p == nil || reflect.ValueOf(p).IsNil()
```

Reference:
https://www.mangatmodi.com/posts/go-check-nil-interface-the-right-way/